# Victory charts not working with react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Im new to react-native and want to use line chart in my small application. 
I came across Victory charts after googling for some time , but unfortunately Im not able to use it.

Error codes on terminal are as follows :

> victory-core@1.4.3 postinstall /Users/.../SampleProject/node_modules/victory-core
>   cd lib || builder run npm:postinstall || (echo 'POSTINSTALL FAILED: If using npm v2, please upgrade to npm v3. See bug https://github.com/FormidableLabs/builder/issues/35' && exit 1)
>
> victory-pie@2.1.0 postinstall /Users/.../SampleProject/node_modules/victory-pie
>   cd lib || builder run npm:postinstall || (echo 'POSTINSTALL FAILED: If using npm v2, please upgrade to npm v3. See bug https://github.com/FormidableLabs/builder/issues/35' && exit 1)
>
> victory-chart@7.0.2 postinstall /Users/.../SampleProject/node_modules/victory-chart
>   cd lib || builder run npm:postinstall || (echo 'POSTINSTALL FAILED: If using npm v2, please upgrade to npm v3. See bug https://github.com/FormidableLabs/builder/issues/35' && exit 1)
>
> victory@0.6.1 postinstall /Users/.../SampleProject/node_modules/victory
>   cd lib || builder run npm:postinstall || (echo 'POSTINSTALL FAILED: If using npm v2, please upgrade to npm v3. See bug https://github.com/FormidableLabs/builder/issues/35' && exit 1)

This is even if I have updated version of npm3.
And the screenshot of simulator :

[image]

Could anybody help regarding this ?

Looking for chart like below : 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming [this](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/victory-chart) is what you are referring to, it uses `react` as well as `svg` to display the graphs, which is HTML DOM. Therefore, it will not work with `react-native`.

Comment: Ok, so do you know any library which can result in chart as mentioned in question ?

Comment: As far as I know, there's hardly any charting libraries out there for react native. You can try things like [react-native-svgkit](https://github.com/brentvatne/react-native-svgkit) middleware, but it's quite tedious.